# Post Tweet using Parse framework

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform

I am having issues posting to twitter via the parse framework. I have logged in my user using this,

```
[PFTwitterUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

I then try to post to twitter using this,

```
NSString *bodyString = @"this is a test";

    // Explicitly percent-escape the '!' character.
    bodyString = [bodyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@"%21"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *tweetRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    tweetRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    tweetRequest.HTTPBody = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:tweetRequest];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Post status synchronously.
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:tweetRequest
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];

    // Handle response.
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
```

which then throws this error,

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
  (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0xac5eac0 
 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json,
 NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json,  
 NSUnderlyingError=0xc0945b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
 (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html for an explanation of the error code. It means "cancelled authentication" so perhaps some problem signing the request?

Answer (score 6):

hope this is in time to be helpful.

First, double check that you have read/write authentication enabled on your Twitter API.

Second, you needed to include the "status=" precursor to the raw text.

Last, you needed full "%" encoding not just the "!".

Here's your code refactored:

```
NSString *bodyString = @"status=this is a test with spaces";

bodyString = [bodyString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *tweetRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
tweetRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
tweetRequest.HTTPBody = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:tweetRequest];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;


// Post status synchronously.
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:tweetRequest
                                 returningResponse:&response
                                             error:&error];

// Handle response.
if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. read/write authentication enabled is the issue for me. i solved it.

Comment: Everyone - don't forget the "status=" !

Answer (score 0):

I've used fabric trying to post a tweet and get it's id as a response , but ,this is not allowed due to twitter developer team answer when i asked if possible , that's why used Parse with this code, could post a tweet and get its id

```
if (![PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:user])
 {
    [PFTwitterUtils linkUser:user block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if ([PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
            NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Twitter!");
            //or put code here to login USER
        }
        else
        {
            [PFTwitterUtils unlinkUserInBackground:user block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error && succeeded) {
                    NSLog(@"The user is no longer associated with their Twitter account.");
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
 else
{
    // here when user logged in with twitter as a parse user

    NSString *status=@"Success";
    NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"status=%@", [status stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Explicitly percent-escape the '!' character.
    bodyString = [bodyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@"%21"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *tweetRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //[user a]
    // [tweetRequest setValue:@"872557363-aeHtbWHK9DjaHsmo6ogI2PcriigIk0IPa0Hk9gAV" forHTTPHeaderField:@"access_token"];
    tweetRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    tweetRequest.HTTPBody = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:tweetRequest];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Post status synchronously.
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:tweetRequest
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];

    // Handle response.
    if (!error) {

        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        NSDictionary * parsedData  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
        NSString *tweetId=[parsedData valueForKey:@"id_str"];
        NSLog(@"the hell tweet id = %@",tweetId);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Swift Version :

```
    if !PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user) {
        PFTwitterUtils.linkUser(user, {
            (succeeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user) {
                println("Woohoo, user logged in with Twitter!")
                let verify = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")
                var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: verify!)
                PFTwitterUtils.twitter()!.signRequest(request)
                var response: NSURLResponse?
               var error:NSError? = nil
                var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

                if let jsonObject: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error:&error) {
                    if let dict = jsonObject as? NSDictionary {
                        NSLog("the hell dist =%@", dict)
                    } else {
                        println("not a dictionary")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Could not parse JSON: \(error!)")
                }
               // dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:, error: NSErrorPointer())

                               }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        var tweetSTr=NSString()
        tweetSTr="tweeted"
        var bodyStr=NSString(format: "status=%@", tweetSTr.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            bodyStr=bodyStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("!", withString: "%21")


        var url=NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
        var tweetRequest=NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        tweetRequest.HTTPMethod="POST"
        tweetRequest.HTTPBody=bodyStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        PFTwitterUtils.twitter().signRequest(tweetRequest)
        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var error:NSError? = nil
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(tweetRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

        if let jsonObject: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error:&error) {
            if let dict = jsonObject as? NSDictionary {
                NSLog("myTweetINfo  =%@", dict)
                var tweetID=NSString()
               tweetID=dict.valueForKey("id_str") as String
                NSLog("myJustPostedTweetID = %@", tweetID)

            } else {
                println("not a dictionary")
            }
        } else {
            println("Could not parse JSON: \(error!)")
        }

    }
```